# How to use polymorphism in ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arraylist, polymorphism, covariance, contravariance

So I have this zoo program where I want to have a list of rooms in a zoo, and a list of cats in each room.

I have 3 classes: `Felid`, `Housecat` and `Wildcat` - `Housecat` and `Wildcat` extend `Felid`. depending on the literal class of animal (right now I have tiger, persian, siamese and cheetah - tiger and cheetah extend wildcat, persian and siamese extend housecat) certain attributes will be automatically assigned.

Class diagram - https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDydn.jpg

For example these are the fields for felid:

```
String speciesName;
String furColour;
String gender;
int weightPounds;
boolean packAnimal;
String habitat;
int age;
```

These are the fields for housecat:

```
String ownerName;
String catName;
boolean feral;
```

These are the fields for wildcat:

```
boolean manEater;
```

In my constructor for housecat I have

```
    if(catName == null || catName.equals("")){
        feral = true;
    }
```

and if the cat's feral, when the user creates a HouseCat with a cat name and uses 'printCatInfo()':

```
@Override
public void printCatInfo(){
    if(feral){
        System.out.println("feral" + "\n" + speciesName + "\n" + furColour + "\n" + gender + 
            "\n" + weightPounds + "lbs\n" + "is not a pack animal" + "\n" + habitat + "\n" + age + " years old (human)");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("owner name is: " + ownerName + "\n" + "cat name is: " + catName + "\n" + speciesName + "\n" + furColour + "\n" + gender + 
            "\n" + weightPounds + "lbs\n" + "is not a pack animal" + "\n" + habitat + "\n" + age + " years old (human)" + "\n");
    }     
}
```

It won't print its name.

```
feral
siamese
White or grey abdomen with black legs, face and tail
male
8lbs
is not a pack animal
urban
7 years old (human)
```

The trouble is that it counted all cats as feral which I assumed was because the list I used for the list of cats is:

```
ArrayList<Felid> catList = new ArrayList<Felid>();
```

So I guess the catName will always be null because the housecats that are added to the list will just count as type 'felid'.

How do I create a list that I can throw all of the cats into and but still treat them as their respective classes?

edit: thanks for pointing out the assignment operator error, it's still only printing feral though

Final edit: Thank you very much to 'DoubleDouble' for pointing out how to use 'Super()' to me - that's not what I expected the problem was. This was the problem:

```
public class Siamese extends HouseCat{
    public Siamese(int weightPounds, int age, String ownerName, String catName, String gender){
        this.speciesName = "siamese";
        this.furColour = "White or grey abdomen with black legs, face and tail";        
        this.ownerName = ownerName;
        this.catName = catName;
        this.weightPounds = weightPounds;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

New code:

```
public class Siamese extends HouseCat{
    public Siamese(int weightPounds, int age, String ownerName, String catName, String gender){
        super(catName);
        this.speciesName = "siamese";
        this.furColour = "White or grey abdomen with black legs, face and tail";        
        this.ownerName = ownerName;
        this.catName = catName;
        this.weightPounds = weightPounds;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

Comment: All housecats are intended to be feral right? I don't see where you would assign a `HouseCat` a `catName`. In any case, since its using the overridden form of `printCatInfo` and printing "feral", it is using the `HouseCat` class (or subclass) and not the `Felid` class's `printCatInfo`

Comment: @DoubleDouble the constructor for subclasses of HouseCat are (for example): 


public Siamese(int weightPounds, int age, String ownerName, String catName, String gender)

Comment: Do you call `super(...)` in your subclasses? If you are relying on the default constructor, it will be called *before* the subclass constructor - meaning your `catName` probably hasn't been assigned yet.

Comment: @DoubleDouble oh so I guess the constructors for the parent classes get called/assigned first? But I can't call super after I've assigned the cat it's name in the 'Siamese' class. So how do I execute: 

    if(catName == null || catName.equals("")){
        feral = true;
    } 

BEFORE

        this.catName = catName;

?

Comment: I think you mean "after", but I've detailed a [solution in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30173716/2974766)

Comment: If you are looking for the cleanest code, you could also call `super()` in `HouseCat` for all the `Felid` fields. Your new code also will assign `this.catName` twice (once in both constructors), which is unnecessary. If you assign all the fields in the right classes, you could even make all your fields `private` and use `public` "getter" and "setter" methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructors seem to the following (correct me if I am wrong):

```
public Siamese(int weightPounds, int age, String ownerName, String catName, String gender)
{
    this.weightPounds = weightPounds;
    this.age = age;
    this.ownerName = ownerName;
    this.catName = catName;
    this.gender = gender;
}

public HouseCat()
{
    if(catName == null || catName.equals(""))
    {
        feral = true;
    }
}
```

Since `ownerName`, `catName`, and `feral` are all a part of the `HouseCat` class, it is best to let the `HouseCat` constructor handle those fields.

```
public HouseCat(String ownerName, String catName)
{
    this.ownerName = ownerName;
    this.catName = catName;
    if(catName == null || catName.equals(""))
    {
        feral = true;
    }
}
```

Siamese looks like this then:

```
public Siamese(int weightPounds, int age, String ownerName, String catName, String gender)
{
    super(ownerName, catName);
    this.weightPounds = weightPounds;
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(feral = true){
```

This is an assignment statement, not a comparison. Use `==`

Answer (score 3):

In this line:

```
if(feral = true){
```

You assigned `true` to `feral`.  You used the assignment operator `=`.  The comparison operator is `==`.  However, `feral` is already a `boolean`, so you can use `feral` itself in the condition.

```
if (feral) {
```

Comment: This is a very good example of why not to use `==` to check a boolean value.